# Values of some EditTexts seem to move to other EditTexts

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I've been having a strange problem with some `EditTexts` that I have in rows of my `ListView`.

Basically the user chooses some exercises from one activity and when he clicks on the next button a new activity launches where he needs to enter information for the exercises that he has chosen. This information includes weights, reps and sets.

Some exercises may not require weights. If this is the case I set the `weight` `EditText` in the `ListView` row to enabled to false:

```
EditText weight = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.weightChosen);

CustomExercisesDB exs = new CustomExercisesDB(cont);
exs.open();

int weightable = exs.isWeightable(chosenExercisesNames.get(position));
exs.close();
if(weightable==0)
{
    weight.setEnabled(false);
}
```

The above code is placed in the `getView` of my custom adapter for the `ListView`.

Now if lets say the user has selected 3 exercises, and one of them doesn't require weights, then the activity where he needs to enter the information for each weight looks like this:
[image]

When the user clicks on the two `EditText` of the first exercise to type some values, the keypad pops up and the user enters some values for each `EditText` in the first exercise.

[image]

Now the issue is when the user lets say hits the return button, the values entered in the `EditTexts` for the first exercise seem to jump to the last two `EditTexts` of the last exercise in the `ListView`. Something like this:

[image]

This is not right as this information should be set for the `Pick Push up`, instead of the `Shoulder press`.

What exactly is causing this problem, and how can I overcome it.

Please tell me if you need anything else from my code that you feel is relevant. I didn't want to include a lot of code that may be irrelevant.

Also if I click back again on one of the `EditTexts` of the first exercise, the values jump back to them from the last exercise. It's like the values I enter are "hanging" outside the `EditTexts` and the keypad popping up seems to make them jump around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

If anyone faces a similar issue, all you have to do is place `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the `manifest` under the activity.

So the activity where I enter the information for each exercise is called `SetCustomExercisesInfo` and I placed `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in it.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SetCustomExercisesInfo"
            android:label="@string/setCusExInfo"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
 </activity>
```

Comment: isn't the problem caused since the listview re-uses views so that if the user has scrolled, the old views from before the scrolling would be shown as new ones?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm not totally sure to be honest.